# In Protractor how can I wait until pop appears without depending on timeout?

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Is there a wait for protractor to wait for the download popup to appear when the report is ready to download without relying on the timeout because some reports might take longer than others?

```
browser.driver.wait(
        this.isVisible(locator)
        , 35000, locator_css + ' took too long to be on the DOM.')
        .then(function() {
            return locator.click();
        });
}
```

Comment: I would prefer using the timeout, otherwise you might endup with infinite loop if the popup did not appear due to some application or network issues.

Comment: You can try to increase the time. I am sure your perf/dev team will have the SLA for the download. Check with them what's the SLA (max time) and provide the same in your code, so that if the popup does not show up by that time it's failure on the application side, which you can/should report.

Comment: Agree with @supputuri. It's important for there to be an understanding of what an acceptable amount of time for the report loading to be. If it takes longer than that then it doesn't matter if it would have loaded eventually... That's a failed test.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to wait for Download Dialog to be visible :

`var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(DownloadDialog), 7000, "Download Dialog Not displayed - Timing Out");`